# UnsatisfiableError: Package conflicts when attempt to create Python 3.4 Conda env

Tags: python, conda

I want to create new Python environment with Conda like this:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.4 -c conda-forge
```

But I get error:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source. 
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done 
Solving environment: / Found conflicts! 
Looking for incompatible packages. This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort. failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Package pip conflicts for: python=3.4 -> pip 
Package vc conflicts for: python=3.4 -> vc=10 
Package vs2010_runtime conflicts for: python=3.4 -> vs2010_runtime
```

Why are there conflicts? I expect that when creating a new fresh environment there should be no conflicts. I am using Miniconda 3 on Windows 10.

Comment: That is indeed strange, especially considering that the only dependency the Conda Forge Python 3.4 builds have is `vs2010_runtime` (no `pip` or `vc`).  Please try specifying an exact package and report back the result: e.g., `conda create -n myenv conda-forge/win-64::python=3.4.5=2`.  Also, you should technically always specify command options (e.g., `-c conda-forge`) before package specs (e.g., `python=3.4`).

Comment: Yes the '-c conda-forge' is not supposed to come after, it's not being treated as a channel arg, but probably as some other arg.

Comment: @merv, I tried with `conda create -n myenv conda-forge/win-64::python=3.4.5=2`. This time another error message appeared: `PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels: - vc=10`.